# How I can showing div element after I hover another div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this jQuery code:

```
menu_btn.hover(function(){
   menu_popup.css('display', 'block');
},function(){
   menu_popup.css('display', 'none');
});
```

It works, after I hover over `menu_btn`, my next `div`(`menu_popup`) is showing. But after I hover over `menu_popup`, `menu_popup` disappears.

How to make sure that when I hover the mouse on the button(`menu_btn`), I show the menu and after I move mouse to menu(`menu_popup`), it does not disappear, and disappear only if I'll take the mouse from this block?

Comment: We need to see the relevant HTML and CSS if you have any.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, why aren't you using either `.toggle()` or `.hide()` and `.show()` instead of `.css('display', 'block')`?

Comment: to keep the hover on the elemnt use CSS ... `menu_popup:hover{display:block}` whatever your menu_popup element is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this without JS, with pure css.

HTML

```
<div id="button">
    hover me
</div>
<div id="my-menu">
    my menu
</div>
```

CSS

```
#my-menu, #button{
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
#my-menu{
    display: none;
}
#button:hover + #my-menu,
#my-menu:hover{
    display: block;
}
```

Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p8pqquc9/

You will have a problem with this solution, if the menu is not directly next to the button and you have to leave the :hover state. In this case the only solution is to set a timeout with js or to use the onclick event.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the jQuery way :

test if the element is hovered or not

```
var isHovered = menu_popup.is(":hover"); // returns true or false
if(!isHovered) {
  //hide menu_popup
}
```